# Creating multiple loops with string read from ascii files in bash

Tags: bash, loops, ifs

I want to create an internal loop inside a loop with strings which are read from ascii files in a bash script. I have two input ascii files which contain a list of strings:

```
files.txt:
filename1
filename2


polls.txt:
CO
NOx
SOx
```

I used IFS and read as following :

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
   printf '%s\n' "$file"

    while IFS= read -r poll; do
       printf '%s\n' "$poll"
       ogrinfo $Database_maindir/$file".shp" -sql "ALTER TABLE $file ADD COLUMN $poll float"
    done < "$Database_maindir/polls.txt"

done < "$Database_maindir/files.txt"
```

I get the following prints and errors:

```
CO
CO
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `/home/CO.shp' with the following drivers.
```

It reads only the string of "polls.txt".

The correct output should be:

```
filename1
CO
ogrinfo /home/"filename1.shp" -sql "ALTER TABLE filename1 ADD COLUMN CO float"
NOx
ogrinfo /home/"filename1.shp" -sql "ALTER TABLE filename1 ADD COLUMN NOx float"
Sox
ogrinfo /home/"filename1.shp" -sql "ALTER TABLE filename1 ADD COLUMN Sox float"

filename2
CO
ogrinfo /home/"filename2.shp" -sql "ALTER TABLE filename2 ADD COLUMN CO float"
NOx
ogrinfo /home/"filename2.shp" -sql "ALTER TABLE filename2 ADD COLUMN NOx float"
Sox
ogrinfo /home/"filename2.shp" -sql "ALTER TABLE filename2 ADD COLUMN Sox float"
```

So, for each file (e.g. filename1, filename2) I want to execute a COMMAND (e.g. an ogrinfo command which updates the columns of a file where the columns are different pollutants listed in the polls.txt.

In the first loop I want to read the strings from the files.txt and keep the string $file with the name of the string (e.g. filename1). In the second loop I want to read the strings from "polls.txt" and keep the string $poll (e.g.CO).

However, it seems that for the first loop it reads the string from the first file it finds , meaning the "polls.txt", so $file gives the string "CO".

How I could define that the first loop should read the second txt file?

Comment: Do you mean `done < "$Database_maindir/$file"`?

Comment: @choroba No. The second loops works correctly if it is alone in the bash script. $file is the name of the string which is read from the "files.txt". E.g. files.txt includes a list of strings : value1 value2 etc. So, $file=value1 for the first loop.

Comment: Some sample input and expected output would help. As it stands right now, you are reading the entirety of `polls.txt` every time you read a line from `files.txt`; is that the intention, or do you want *one* loop that reads a single line from each file per iteration?

Comment: In its simplest form, `while read file; read -u 3 poll; do ...; done < files.txt 3< poll.txt`.

Comment: @chepner I had already edited my question. The answer is yes, I want a loop that reads a single line from each file.

Comment: @chepner the number 3 is the number of strings only for the polls.txt? Because in fact the number of strings in the two files will not be equal

Comment: No, the 3 refers to file descriptor 3, as opposed to file descriptor 0 (for standard input).

Comment: Are you *sure* the outer loop is actually reading from `files.txt`, and you didn't specifying `polls.txt` by accident? I don't see how the code you are showing could produce the claimed output. What happens if you comment out the inner loop completely?

Comment: I've copied your code, inserted `echo` before `ogringo` and got correct output.

Comment: It seems finally that the problem is shown when I repeat the the internal loop more than 1 time inside the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try with awk :

```
awk '
  NR == FNR {
    a[$0]
    next
    }
  {
    for ( i in a )
      printf( "system ogringo %s %s\n" , $0 , i )
  }
' polls.txt files.txt
```

I know nothing about sql but perhaps you can have only one command for each file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use dedicated file descriptors. That way you are 100% sure each `read` reads from the proper stream. And the commands inside the loop also don't read from the stream.

```
while IFS= read -r -u 3 file; do
   printf '%s\n' "$file"

    while IFS= read -r -u 4 poll; do
       printf '%s\n' "$poll"
       echo ogrinfo $Database_maindir/$file".shp" -sql "ALTER TABLE $file ADD COLUMN $poll float"
    done 4< "$Database_maindir/polls.txt"

done 3< "$Database_maindir/files.txt"
```

2. Use an unreadable script which first merges two files together by repeating the first one the number of lines the second one has, and then repeating each line in the second one by the number of lines in the first and then runs xargs (ideas for repeating from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521465/how-can-i-repeat-the-content-of-a-file-n-times) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594554/repeat-each-line-in-a-text-n-times))

```
paste <(
    awk -v nr=$(wc -l <polls.txt) \
        '{for (i = 1; i <= nr; i++) print}' files.txt
) <(
    seq $(wc -l <files.txt) |
    xargs -n1 cat polls.txt
) |
xargs -n2 sh -c 'echo ogrinfo "$1".shp -sql "ALTER TANLE $1 ADD COLUMN $2 float"' --
```

Comment: I tried the option 1 but I got the following error: read: 3: invalid file descriptor: Bad file descriptor. This would also work if the internal loop (i,e. $poll) is called more than one time inside the outer loop ($file) ?

Comment: @Nat Works [here](http://tpcg.io/F7kZYR) . `$poll` is not a "call", it's a "variable expansion". You can do a variable expansion any time you want. I don't get what you ask, the variable is not valid in the outer loop, after the inner loop it will retain the last value.

Comment: For example, in the tutorials point ,in line 21 (after the inner loop) if you try to repeat the loop described in lines 17-21 (with a different ogrinfo command) then it doesn't work it gives the error read: 3: invalid file descriptor: Bad file descriptor.

Comment: If you copy the lines 17-21 below line 22 it will just execute the loop two times. I don't understand you. The error comes from `read -u 3` - from `read` reading from 3rd file descriptor. Nothing will save you from understanding the commands, if you aim to modify it.