# Is it possible to move files in groups to a directory that needs to change every four files?

Tags: bash, for-loop

I appreciate the title may not have been clear, but I couldn't find a better way to word it.
Essentially, I would like to know if it is possible to tell the shell to

a) move the first four files to directory a

b) move the second group of four files to directory b
and so on for approximately a thousand files.

However, the names of directory a and directory b (and all the others) have nothing in common, so I understand that I would have to create a script that watches

a) the number of files moved,

b) the number of directories that already have all the files needed in them, and

c) which directory to write to next (I assume that will involve some kind of shell-assigned numerical ordering of the directories).

Also, this is complicated by the fact that not all of the directories will have four files associated with them at finish, so I need some way of telling the shell that these directories are finished (i.e. they contain all the files that are associated with them).

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: The files that need to be moved are .zip files, of the form 'x_y_z.zip', where

x = a string that is common to all the files

y = a string that identifies which file belongs to which group

z = a string that is unique to each nth file in each group.

Some groups contain fewer files, but there is never a group that has more than four files in it.

What I need to do is go through the directory, file by file, and move the .zip files that share 'y' to another directory that contains that group and only that group. The problem I'm having is that the directory names cannot contain 'y', and so I need a way to have the shell notice when 'y' has changed and move the file to the next directory in the list.

EDIT 2: So I've broadly speaking worked out what I need to do - if I can put all the names of the zip files in a .txt file, and all the names of the target directories in another, I can tell the shell to read from the directory.txt and use that as the target of a mv command. The only problem I'm having is how to tell the shell to go to the next directory when 'y' changes, but I think I've gotten around that. All I need now is a command to mv the first file in the file.txt to the first directory in the directory.txt. Here's what I have so far:

```
!/bin/bash

cd ~/Downloads/ZIP
ls -rt *.zip > file.txt

a=1

for i in *.zip
do
    mv 'line a of file.txt' 'line a of directory.txt' 
    let a=a+1
done
```

The ls -rt command is necessary because whilst the files do possess some kind of identification system, it has absolutely nothing to do with the id system I'm using, but thankfully I created the files in the order that the directories are listed in the directory.txt file.

Comment: it is like scrambled egg :|

Comment: My analogy was 'maelstrom of death', but eggs works too.

Comment: Sadly, I don't think you have quite completely defined your problem well enough for us to help. In what conditions are some folders considered filled? Which 4 files have to move to which folder? Perhaps answering one of those questions yourself will help you solve the problem.

Comment: If your list of directories can be written in a file, maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54870417/creating-multiple-loops-with-string-read-from-ascii-files-in-bash) will give you an idea. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dup'd file descriptors to the rescue.
How's this?

```
last=''                          # pre-sets the comparator to empty
while read -u 4 file             # read a filename 
do IFS=_ read x y z <<< "$file"  # splits filename on _ for y
   if [[ "$y" != "$last" ]]      # when it has changed
   then read -u 3 dir            # reads from the dirs file
        last="$y"                # updates comparator
   fi
   mv "$file" "$dir/"            # does the move
done 3< dirs 4< files            # this assigns the streams to fd's
```

The default fd (file descriptor) for stdin in 0.
We are assigning a new fd of 3 specifically as the file of dirs, and another as 4 for the file of filenames. This is done for the scope of the loop with the line

```
done 3< dirs 4< files
```

You can change the filenames. I used `dirs` and `files` for my testing.

`read -u 3 dir` reads explicitly from the fd #3, so it doesn't consume anything else, such as a filename.
`read -u 4 file` reads explicitly from the fd #4, so it doesn't consume anything else, such as a directory.
This keeps them both concurrently readable.

My manual page, for your convenience:

```
read [-ers] [-a aname] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars] [-p prompt] [-t  timeout]  [-u  fd]  [name
   ...]
  One line is read from the standard input, or from the
  file descriptor fd supplied as an argument to the -u 
  option, and the first word is assigned to the first name,
  the second word to the second name, and so on, with 
  leftover words and their intervening separators assigned
  to the last name.  If there are fewer words read from the 
  input stream than names, the remaining names are assigned
  empty values. The characters in IFS are used to split
  the line into words. The backslash character (\) may be
  used to remove any special meaning for the next character
  read and for line continuation.

Options, if supplied, have the following meanings:
  -u fd      Read input from file descriptor fd.
```

and for completeness...

```
  -a aname   The  words are assigned to sequential indices
             of the array variable aname, starting at 0. 
             aname is unset before any new values are
             assigned.  Other name arguments are ignored.
  -d delim   The first character of delim is used to 
             terminate the input line, rather than newline.
  -e         If the standard input is coming from a
             terminal, readline (see READLINE above) is used
             to obtain the  line. Readline uses the current
             (or default, if line editing was not previously
             active) editing settings.
  -i text    If readline is being used to read the line,
             text is placed into the editing buffer before
             editing begins.
  -n nchars  read returns  after reading nchars characters
             rather than waiting for a complete line of 
             input, but honor a delimiter if fewer than 
             nchars characters are read before the
             delimiter.
  -N nchars  read returns after reading exactly nchars
             characters rather than waiting for a complete
             line of input, unless EOF is encountered or
             read times out. Delimiter characters
             encountered in the input are not treated
             specially and do not cause read to return until
             nchars characters are read.
  -p prompt  Display prompt on standard error, without a
             trailing newline, before attempting to read any
             input. The prompt is displayed only if input is
             coming from a terminal.
  -r         Backslash does not act as an escape character. 
             The backslash is considered to be  part  of the                     
             line. In particular, a backslash-newline pair 
             may not be used as a line continuation.
  -s         Silent mode.  If input is coming from a
             terminal, characters are not echoed.
  -t timeout Cause read to time out and return failure if a
             complete line of input is not read within
             timeout seconds. timeout may be a decimal
             number with a fractional portion following the
             decimal point. This  option  is only effective
             if read is reading input from a terminal, pipe,
             or other special file; it has no effect when
             reading from regular files. If timeout is 0,
             read  returns  success if input is available on
             the specified file descriptor, failure
             otherwise. The exit status is greater than 128
             if the timeout is exceeded.
```

Comment: if there's any chance you're missing a `\n` on the last line of the files, add `|| [[ -n "$file" ]]` to that read.

Comment: This is a very good answer, and based on my (admittedly amateurish) reading of the code, this would be perfect for me if all of the folders had exactly four files associated with them. I think my incompetence is showing again, I don't see any obvious way to convert this into a loop that checks for a change in the 'y' string.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and I'm very grateful for it. Although, it does me no good since the 'read' that I seem to have doesn't match https://ss64.com/bash/read.html, which I assume is the one mentioned in your answer.
Hence, I get : /home/iridium/Scripts/READ.sh: line 7: read: filenames.txt: invalid file descriptor specification. Still, this should work, so thanks for your time.

Comment: did you change `4<files` to `4<filenames.txt` on the last line? `file` is a variable name.

Comment: huh. That page does say `-u fd  Read input from file descriptor fd.` but doesn't list `-u` at the top.

Comment: Oh. I though I was supposed to replace the numbers with the filenames.txt and directories.txt in the script itself, rather than after the 'done'. Retried, and success. Thank you.
Also, my man page for read does not match that page:
SYNOPSIS
       #include <unistd.h>

       ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);

is literally all I have.
I suppose my only question is how does it work?

Comment: You're looking at the C language function. c.f. [here](https://ss64.com/bash/read.html), or `man 1 read`.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you immensely.

Comment: You're welcome. If it works as well as we hope, come back and upvote it, lol. ;)

Comment: Will do when reputation > 15.

Answer (score 0):

I think, just based on my naive reading of your problem that you might be overthinking it slightly. If y is a string that identifies the group then you just have to move each file into the folder 'y' based on what 'y' is in each file?

something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in ./x*; do
    middle=$( echo "$filename" | cut -d\_ -f2 |tr -d "\n" | od -An -t uC)
    mkdir -p $middle;
    mv $filename $middle;
done
```

This will move each file into a folder 'y' based on 'y' for that file.
If the directory doesn't exist it will create it. It should be run from the same directory as the files.

If i misunderstood and you really do need to check the amount going into each directory it should be easy enough to add that as another loop inside the existing one, simply reading the the 'z' value.

Comment: That is exactly what I would like to do, but the folders already exist, and have names that are nothing to do with 'y'. That being said, you've actually just given me the answer. I created the folders for the files first, but I've realised that was a mistake when I could just wait for the files to be created and then rename the directory. Thank you.

Comment: hey i fixed it so it uses a different name for the folder. This way the folder is name after the int representation of y. if y is more complicated you can just adjust that final "od" to be some other change. Even just prepending an integer to every folder would work fine. easy to cleanup in the end as well.